# How to remove unknown zero-width character from string?

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation, text

I have text that contains a zero-width character that I am not able to remove.  A minimum example is in `str` below where the character is at the start of the text.

```
str = "​​4-6";
res = ToExpression /@ 
  StringSplit[StringReplace[str, WhitespaceCharacter -> ""], "-"]
```

> ```
> {​​4, 6}
> ```

```
Head /@ res
```

> ```
> {Symbol, Integer}
> ```

This character (or these types of characters) are at various locations in the imported text.

They do not appear to fall into `WhitespaceCharacter` as `StringReplace` does not match to them and I don't know their locations before-hand so I can't use `StringReplacePart`.

How do I clean these unknown zero-width character from strings?

Comment: Why not use `StringSplit[str, Except[WordCharacter]]`? It would remove white space characters including the ones overlooked by `WhitespaceCharacters`. Your example doesn't look as if you want to remove *only* the two invisible ones.

Comment: @Jens This approach will not work for the actual strings as they contain text as well.  It is actually a TSV with these characters peppered throughout the fields for some unknown reason.

Comment: Then maybe you could use the approach in my answer directly upon import, i.e., set the `CharacterEncoding -> "ASCII"` and then remove the offending `\:xxxx`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can see the zero-width character using FullForm:

```
str //FullForm
```

> "\:200b\:200b4-6"

So, in this case, you can use the following:

```
StringReplace[str, "​\:200b"->""] //FullForm
```

> "4-6"

**Update**

*Added a threshold, default 2, for determining "zero" width characters*

You can use the following function to look for zero-width characters in your string:

```
findZeroWidthCharacters[str_, threshold_:2] := With[
    {chars = DeleteDuplicates[Characters[str]]},

    Cases[
        Rasterize[
            Row @ MapThread[
                Tooltip,
                {chars, ToCharacterCode[StringJoin@chars]}
            ],
            "Regions"
        ],
        Rule[{code_, _}, {{l_, _}, {r_, _}}] /; r-l<=threshold :> code
    ]
]
```

Here I apply it to your string:

```
findZeroWidthCharacters[str]
```

> {8203}

Here I apply it to a longer string:

```
s = ExampleData[{"Text", "AliceInWonderland"}] <> FromCharacterCode[{8203, 8204, 8207}];
StringLength[s]

findZeroWidthCharacters[s] //AbsoluteTiming
```

> 51725
>
> {0.170908, {8203, 8204, 8207}}

Comment: This is too specific to the particular zero-width character in this particular string. I don't know how many other types of these characters are in the string.

Comment: @Kuba The slowest part of the code is the use of `Rasterize`, so it would be better to only use `Rasterize` once.

Comment: Indeed, rookie mistake, time to sleep then. +1ed

Comment: This is not working with Mma 11.1.0 on Win 8.1 Pro. I get an empty string back. Which version and OS are you using?

Comment: I use M11.1 on OSX. What does `Rasterize[
  Row[{Tooltip[FromCharacterCode[8203], 8203], Tooltip["a", "a"], 
    Tooltip[FromCharacterCode[8204], 8204]}], "Regions"]` return?

Comment: @CarlWoll `{{8203, "Tooltip"} -> {{0., 6.}, {1., 13.}}, {"a", 
   "Tooltip"} -> {{1., 6.}, {8., 12.}}, {8204, 
   "Tooltip"} -> {{8., 1.}, {10., 15.}}}`

Comment: @Edmund See the update

Comment: This looks very promising. I'll hold off on the accept just in case. :-)

Answer (score 5):

how about:

```
ascii = StringJoin@ FromCharacterCode[Range[0, 127]]; 
 StringReplace[str, c_ /; StringFreeQ[ascii, c] -> ""]
Head /@ ToExpression/@StringSplit[%, "-"]
```

> {Integer, Integer}

or even `FromCharacterCode[Select[ToCharacterCode[str], # <= 127 &]]`

You might even extend that range if you have printable non-ascii characters.
In your example the offending character is # 8203

Comment: Interesting approach. Does not seem unicode friendly..

Comment: right, as I said you may need to adjust the character range to suit your needs.  ( You could even turn it around and just filter out 8203 )

Answer (score 3):

Following a similar logic to george2079:

```
StringReplace[ImportString[ExportString[str,"Text", CharacterEncoding->"ASCII"]],
"\\:"~~Repeated[HexadecimalCharacter,4]->""]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
clean[x_Symbol] := ToExpression@Last@Characters@ToString@x
clean[x_Integer] := x

Head /@ clean /@ res
```

> {Integer, Integer}

Comment: I do not know the position of these zero-width characters before hand in the string so a position based method such as this will not be effective. Also they occur in text and number strings. I only gave a minimal example to demonstrate the character's existence.